# AVAudioEngine stops device's background audio

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avaudioengine

I am using an `AVAudioEngine` object, that has many `AVAudioPlayerNodes` attached to it. The audio all works fine, except it stops any audio that the iPhone is playing in the background (i. e. from iTunes or another music app).

When my app is opened, it stops any other background audio. Is there a way to allow background audio to continue to play? Even when my app is using AVAudioPlayerNodes to play audio itself?

Answer (score 3):

Music App has it's own audioSession, that makes audio engine stops, i had that problem too, please restart after music app.

```
func stepB_startEngine(){
    if  engine.running == false {
        do { try engine.start() }
        catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

setup audioSettion also:

```
func setUpAudioSession(){
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.ambient, options: .mixWithOthers)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: Order seems to be important here. It only works for me if `setUpAudioSession` is called before starting the engine.